# How to scrape location data from a leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy, leaflet

I want to access the location (latitude, longitude) of the water level sensor markers found in [this website](https://app.pub.gov.sg/waterlevel/pages/LargeMap.aspx) but I can't find any HTML tags which contains their locations.

Any guidance would be very helpful!

Comment: if you want to do it manually, use Network tab in your browser. You have a few requests that bring the data, you get it raw there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the network inspector, you can see that the page sends a GET request which looks like an API call: `https://app.pub.gov.sg/waterlevel/pages/GetWLInfo.aspx?type=WL&d=2023-08-15T07:00:00.000Z`

By visiting the API endpoint, you can find the current data for all sensors, which you can get with the following:

```py
import requests

# Fetch data
endpoint = "https://app.pub.gov.sg/waterlevel/pages/GetWLInfo.aspx"
params = {"type": "WL"}
response = requests.get(endpoint, params=params)
return response.content.decode("utf-8")

# Parse data
dataSplit = [[data for data in sensor.split("$#$")] for sensor in raw.split("$#$$@$")]
data = []
for record in dataSplit:
    # Convert data to dict and typecast
    if record not in data and len(record) == 7:
        data.append(
            {
                "sensor-id": record[0],
                "sensor-name": record[1],
                "latitude": float(record[3]),
                "longitude": float(record[2]),
                "water-level": float(record[4]),
                "status": float(record[5]),
                "timestamp": parseTimestamp(record[6]),
            }
        )

# Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

To parse timestamps, use the following:

```py
def parseTimestamp(timestamp: str):
    # Standardise timestamp
    timestamp = timestamp.split(" ")
    while "" in timestamp:
        timestamp.remove("")
    # Pad day
    if len(timestamp[1]) < 2:
        timestamp[1] = "0" + timestamp[1]
    # Pad time
    if len(timestamp[-1].split(":")[0]) < 2:
        timestamp[-1] = "0" + timestamp[-1]
    timestamp = " ".join(timestamp)
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%b %d %Y  %I:%M%p")
    return timestamp
```